Vuejs bootstrap Form Group layout error: label-cols 6/12 of cols 4 not equal to label-cols 2/12 of cols 12?
In vuejs bootstrap I have code like below, with:

First row is <b-col cols="12"> and <b-form-group with label-cols="2"

Second row start with <b-col cols="4"> and <b-form-group with label-cols="6"

Third row start with <b-col cols="6"> and <b-form-group with label-cols="4"


So that each of 3 labels should has expected cols = (2/12) * 12 = (6/12) * 4 = (4/12) * 6 = 2 columns in width in Bootstrap Grid system (12 columns per row).
But as in image below, you could see the width of all 3 labels is not the same. What could be the possible reason (and solution to fix)?
<div>
  <b-card no-body>
    <div class="m-1">
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="12">
          <validation-provider
            #default="{ errors }"
            rules="required"
            name=" "
          >
            <b-form-group
              label-align-sm="left"
              label-cols="2"
              label="label 1"
              label-for="code1"
              label-class="label-required"
            >
              <b-form-input
                id="code1"
                v-model="code1"
                maxlength="30"
                :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
              />
              <small class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</small>

            </b-form-group>
          </validation-provider>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="4">
          <validation-provider
            #default="{ errors }"
            rules="required"
            name=" "
          >
            <b-form-group
              label-align-sm="left"
              label-cols="6"
              label="label 2"
              label-for="code2"
              label-class="label-required"
            >
              <b-form-input
                id="code2"
                v-model="code2"
                maxlength="30"
                :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
              />
              <small class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</small>

            </b-form-group>
          </validation-provider>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="8">
          zzzz
        </b-col>
      </b-row>

      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="6">
            <b-form-group
              label-align-sm="left"
              label-cols="4"
              label="label 3"
              label-for="code3"
            >
              <b-form-input
                id="code3"
                v-model="code3"
                maxlength="30"
              />
            </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="2">
          bbbb
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="4">
          cccc
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
        </div>
    </b-card>
</div>



I'm not overly familiar with BootstrapVue, but if you want all of the labels to be the same width, then I'd imagine the label-cols value should be the same for each (you have then as 2,6 and 8)

@paddyfields <b-form-group> is nested in <b-col>, so that its width depends on its parent b-col. For e.g, if I have <b-col cols="m" id="B"> and a <b-form-group label-cols="n" id="C">, then width of C should be n/12 of m, that is (n/12)*m
